# Create a measure in MDX for a set of Members

Tags: mdx, measure

I need something as following:

```
with member Measures.Test2 as (Measures.Test, {[Assets Monthly].[Disbursed Date].&[2014], [Assets Monthly].[Disbursed Date].&[2015]})
select Measures.Test2 on columns
from databaseX
```

It works only if I set it with only one member, ex:

```
with member Measures.Test2 as (Measures.Test, [Assets Monthly].[Disbursed Date].&[2014])
```

The error that I get in the first case is:

> The  function expects a string or numeric expression for the 
>   argument. A tuple set expression was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Against `AdvWrks`:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER Measures.Test2 AS 
    Sum
    (
      {
        [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2006]
       ,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2007]
      }
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  Measures.Test2 ON COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Your script:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER Measures.Test2 AS 
    Sum
    (
      {
        [Assets Monthly].[Disbursed Date].&[2014]
       ,[Assets Monthly].[Disbursed Date].&[2015]
      }
     ,Measures.Test
    ) 
SELECT 
  Measures.Test2 ON COLUMNS
FROM databaseX;
```

This is prettier. Created a calculated member on the Date hierarchy and chuck the measures in the `WHERE` slicer:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[testPeriod] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      {
        [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2006]
       ,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2007]
      }
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Date].[Calendar].[testPeriod] ON COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount];
```